# Get input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input

```
<input value="25" data-hidden-value="25" name="associations[agencies][ids][]" 
           data-hidden-name="associations[agencies][ids][]" class="string" type="hidden">
```

This input is dynamically generated, and don't have any ID. I'm trying to get the value using the following code:

```
campaignId = $("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]]'").val();
```

But I always get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong selector. Try this

```
$('input[name="associations[agencies][ids][]"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your selector - you closed the first opening [ in the wrong place. Proper line should be:

```
campaignId = $("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]']").val();
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error at `input[name='xxx']` , the last single quote should be inside the last `]`

change

`$("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]]'")`

to

`$("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]']")`

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change the value of name that you are provided `$("input[name='xyz']")` you just misplace the `]` inside the `'`

```
$("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]]'").val()
```

to

```
 $("input[name='associations[agencies][ids][]']").val()
```